# GetWindowRect is not working as I thought it should

Tags: c#, winapi, overlay

I am setting up an overlay program for the game Elite Dangerous.
The overlay does not want to keep the size of the game window when the window is moved.
Whenever the window is being moved the overlay expands and retracts relative to the program, and I do not want that.
Here is an video showing the problem https://youtu.be/DYeHYOOOIkM.

I have been googling around for a few hours to try and fix this issue but I cannot find any answers at all.
All I could find and fix was top and left position, not the expanding issue.

```cs
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out Rectangle IpRect);

[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, ref WINDOWINFO pwi);

private Rectangle _newWindowSize;

private void TimerRePositionOverlayWindow_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetWindowRect(handle, out _newWindowSize);

    Top = _newWindowSize.Top + 31;
    Left = _newWindowSize.Left + 8;
    Width = _newWindowSize.Width;
    Height = _newWindowSize.Height;

    Console.WriteLine($"{_newWindowSize}");
}
```

I expect the size should be the exact same as the game window size.
Not expanding and retracting.

Comment: Is `Rectangle` compatible with `LPRECT`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I am using the built in Rectangle variable for _newWindowSize, I don't know if it is compatible with LPRECT

Comment: It is not compatible, RECT does not have a Width and Height.  http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/WINDOWINFO.html

Comment: @HansPassant I am using Rectangle, it has width and height

Comment: Right, that was your mistake.  You must declare RECT yourself.

Comment: Why wont Rectangle work the same way as RECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a Rectangle is not a `RECT`. They appear to contain the same information, but they are very, very different objects.

Assume for a moment that you are a method, and that you expect an exercise book to write your data into. If I hand you an exercise book, you know to open it by turning the front cover and write your data in there. You then hand me back the book.

If on the other hand, I pass you a dictionary, your can open the cover ok, but then you then write your data all over the word definitions, and hand the result back to me. I look at it, but I can't make sense of the data, or the words any more as they are mixed together.

If a routine wants a specific structure, give it one. Otherwise, it will treat what you give it as if it was the structure it asked for, and no-body will be happy!

So what you should do is :

> Encapsulate it: write a method that accepts / returns a Rectangle, but
>   which creates the RECT internally and hands that to the GetWindowRect
>   function.